# How to keep socket (tcp) connection active when app goes to background in windows phone 8

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-8, tcp, background-agent

As i am new to Windows phone development and i am struggling to find a solution that how to maintain a tpc socket connection active when my app goes to background in windows phone 8.

can any one suggest me or help me out to find an approach to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

--Ram

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in Windows Phone, as all 3rd party apps are frozen and stored in RAM when not in focus. You have to make sure the user knows not to exit the app while an active TCP connection is being used.

As for background processes on Windows Phone, you can achieve that by using Background Agents. More information available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), although I don't believe this will be very suitable for your needs.